# Youtube embedded videos are showing no video indexed in google search console

Tags: video, iframe, youtube, google-search-console, noindex

I have more than 10-15 YouTube embedded videos on my website. When I check on Google Search Console, all the videos are showing the below message:

> No video indexed - this video won't appear on this page on Google Search

Any idea how to solve this issue?

```
<iframe width="auto" height="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9VsEAEX6C9Q?si=lsrdFtFU-1c-VZ2i" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

If I click on live test the URL then I get the video

[image]

But if I click on google index then it's not showing
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your website's robots.txt file doesn't disallow Google from crawling the embedded video pages. Googlebot should be able to access these pages to index the content.

Comment: I have 10-15 videos and 11 videos are showing no video index and 4 showing indexed. I don't think show the robots.txt file disallows Google.

Answer (score 0):

The requirements for video indexing are these, a video is eligible for indexing on a page only when it meets the following criteria:

- A video must be embedded within a host page. A video without a host page will not be indexed, even if the video is included in a video sitemap.
- The host page must be indexed. This means that the page can't be blocked by a robots.txt rule, a noindex rule, or anything else that might prevent indexing. Use the URL Inspection tool to see whether the host page has been indexed (or if it is capable of being indexed). It also means that the video must be in the canonical page, because only canonical pages are indexed.
- The video must be prominent on both mobile and desktop versions of the page. When video isn't the main content of the page, prominence is used as a signal to determine which video to index on the page. More about prominence.
- The video must be appropriately sized. Google can index a video only if it fulfills the following size requirements:
  Height: 140-1080 pixels
  Width: 140 pixels or wider
  The video must be at least 1/3 of the screen width, but not wider than the screen
- The video location must be central on the page.
  The entire video must be inside the renderable area of the page.
  The video must not be too far right or too low on the page. The user must be able to see the entire video when the page loads.
- A valid thumbnail is required. You should provide a valid thumbnail, although Google might be able to generate a thumbnail for you from the video file, if the file can be fetched.
- Can be rendered. The video can't be hidden behind other elements or require complex interaction for the player to appear. Google can sometimes navigate simple interactions (such as a "tap to play" interaction), but this isn't guaranteed.
- The video must be playable within the page. Outbound links to another video hosting page are not counted as videos, but a link to another page to play the video won't enable indexing on this page.
- The video must be in a format that Google supports. Google judges the video format based on the file extension. On pages where the video is the main content on the page, Google might ignore the file extension when attempting to index a video, and so you won't see unsupported format errors on these types of pages.
- The video must follow the best practices for video files.
  Provide consistent metadata. You should provide the same title, thumbnail URL, and video URL in all sources (sitemap, HTML tags, meta tags, and structured data) that describe the same video on the same page.
- A video need not be fetched to be indexed, but a successful fetch makes the video eligible for additional features such as autoplay previews that can significantly improve user engagement.

They should help you understand why those videos weren't indexed, despite being seen by Google.